# Which algorithm does Mathematica use for FindClique?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

Does anyone know which algorithms Mathematica use for computing `FindClique[g]` and `FindClique[g,{n}]`
    (finds a maximal clique containing exactly `n` vertices)?

Comment: you can see the definition  of the function called by `FindClique` using ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions[GraphComputation`GraphCliqueDump`findClique]``

Comment: @kglr In WL 12.1, I get an error. `FindClique[g]` finds the largest clique in the graph g. Is it means finding a maximum clique or something else?
If yes, it is an NP problem, and to solve it, we have to use a heuristic solution, which one WL uses for that?

Comment: Why do you want to know? (It's a serious question.)

Comment: try ``PrintDefinitions[GraphComputation`InternalFindClique] `` and click on the link to get the notebook that gives definition of `findClique`.

Comment: @kglr I don't think that spelunking will give a productive answer to this question.  I really wonder if OP wants to know the specific algorithm Mathematica uses, or if he just wants to know how to find maximal cliques, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm

Comment: @Szabolcs, the code is not too long and it looks like the core method is just LP.

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to know which algorithm WL uses to compute a maximal clique. The reason for that is straightforward. I'm planning to use it as one of the phases of the solution of a "big" problem. Before to use 
it as a "black box" I prefer to understand the prof and con of the "black box."

Comment: It seems to me that then the right thing to research is how to find maximal cliques, not how Mathematica does it specifically.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko First, you don't *have* to use a heuristic to find a maximum cliques. Indeed, there are very good exact solvers for the problem. Second, IIRC, `FindClique` just finds a maximal clique but there's no guarantee a larger clique wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Juho  Can you suggest a good solver of this problem, where the size of the graph is around 40K nodes and 2-3M edges?

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I didn't explain myself correctly. A maximal clique is one of the steps of the whole solution. To find the maximal clique, I would use WL  so I want to understand this function in more detail

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko For which problem? Finding a maximum clique or a maximal clique? If you want maximum cliques, google for pmc. Another solver is cliquer which is older but still solid.

Comment: @Juho `FindClique[g]` does in fact find a maximum clique.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko There are three separate things here: 1) *what problem* does `FindClique` solve? 2) *How* does it solve it? 3) How can on solve that problem, in general? (1) is relevant, (3) is also a useful thing to ask, but not for this QA site. (2) is on-topic, but in my opinion quite pointless to ask. If you insist anyway, realistically, your options are what kglr said (read the code) or to ask Wolfram Support. I predict they will not give you any satisfactory answer though. If you want to use a program whose implementation is completely open and documented, I recommend IGraph/M.

Comment: @Juho Thank you. I  look for  the maximal cliques solver

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your comments and the ranks that you give to my question. In this case, I can't use IGraph/M.

Comment: @kglr Do you have any evidence that that is the function that `FindClique` is actually using? `FindClique`'s definition is hidden. It may not be using `InternalFindClique`. `InternalFindClique` may be an unrelated experimental implementation. Notably, `InternalFindClique` seems to ignore the `size` argument. So I don't think this is what `FindClique` really uses ...

Comment: @Szabolcs, very good point. I don't.

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave the answer below as an explanation of what `` GraphComputation`InternalFindClique `` does, but I am not convinced that `FindClique` really uses `` GraphComputation`InternalFindClique ``. `InternalFindClique` seems to simply ignore its `size` argument.

---

@kglr commented that the source code is actually readable using

```
PrintDefinitions[GraphComputation`InternalFindClique]
```

[image]

It appears that `FindClique` finds independent vertex sets in the complement graph, which is an equivalent problem. It solves the independent vertex set problem using an integer linear programming (ILP) formulation which it passes to [`LinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html).

What's implemented here is:

> Maximize
>   $$\sum_{i \in V} w_i x_i$$
>   subject to the constraints $x_i + x_j \le 1$ for all edges $(i,j)$ (independence) and $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all vertices $i$.

$i$ denotes vertices, $w_i$ denotes vertex weights, and $x_i 
= 1$ means that vertex $i$ is part of the independent vertex set that was found.

I am not very familiar with ILP, but some googling suggests that this is a standard formulation, e.g. see [this link](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/attachments/LinearProgramming/lp.pdf).

---

This answers your question about what method `FindClique` uses in Mathematica 12.1.

There are many other methods to find maximal cliques. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Algorithms) lists several.

As far as I know, the most widely used method to solve this problem is the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm).

Another way to find maximal cliques in Mathematica is to use [igraph's implementation](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Cliques.html#igraph_maximal_cliques) through IGraph/M. The igraph documentation was the following note:

> The current implementation uses a modified Bron-Kerbosch algorithm to find the maximal cliques, see: David Eppstein, Maarten Löffler, Darren Strash: [Listing All Maximal Cliques in Sparse Graphs in Near-Optimal Time.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-17517-6_36) Algorithms and Computation, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 6506, 2010, pp 403-414.